# Android String.Contains("\\^") not Working despite Escaping the Special Character?

Tags: android, string

I am trying to check whether a String contains a Caret Character by doing this:

```
if (text.contains("\\^")) {
    break;
}
```

This does not seem to work at all despite the Fact that I have used the Escape Characters properly as specified in several Stack overflow Answers and the text Contains the Caret character.

What am I doing wrong or What are some alternatives? 
Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why are you escaping? See this: https://ideone.com/tpA9Dx

```
import java.util.*;
import java.lang.*;
import java.io.*;

/* Name of the class has to be "Main" only if the class is public. */
class Ideone
{
    public static void main (String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception
    {
        if ("^".contains("^")) {
            System.out.println("YES");
        }
    }
}
```

Output:

> Success   time: 0.1 memory: 320256 signal:0 YES

Simply use: `text.contains("^")`

Answer (score 2):

You dont have to escape ^ inside ""

the meaning of `text.contains("\\^")` is it is actually looking for \\^ inside your text.

so it will match string like hii\\^,hell\\^

in order to match ^ inside your text just write `text.contains("^")`
it will match all string that contains ^
for example : hii^,hello^

sample prog

```
class Regex2
{
        public static void main(String args[])
        {
                String text = "hiiihow^";
                if(text.contains("^"))
                {
                        System.out.println("Yes");
                }
                else
                {
                        System.out.println("no");
                }
        }
}
```

output:
Yes